# Web Mercator Projection - EPSG ID

Tags: here-api, mercator

I am currently using as tile provider, the HERE API.

I was not able to find out the information neither in the HERE API documentation, neither here.

I'd like to know if the "projection" used by the HERE API corresponds to the Web Mercator projection, i.e. the one defined here : https://epsg.io/3857, which is the one used by all the main web tile providers, such as google maps, openstreetmap, bing, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Having read their [FAQ](https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/enterprise-map-tile/topics/faq.html) it seems more than possible that they are using the web mercator. See around

> How do I calculate the distance to the ground depending on the zoom level?

where they are discussing the limitations of the Mercator projection.

Comment: mercator and web mercator are different projection systems. The web mercator is a simple one where the Earth is approximated by a sphere, rather than an ellipsoid. This simplifies the 2D X,Y computation, which is required for web mapping services. So i don't think the FAQ provides a clarification.